# Using two static classes having same name in C#

Tags: c#, dll, static-classes

I have a DLL which I have included in my C# project. Let's call it "one.dll"
This DLL contain a static class named "staticclass"

I have another DLL which I have also included in same project. Let's call it "two.dll"
This DLL also contain a static class named "staticclass"

Now when I include both DLLs at the same time in my project and try to access "staticclass" then naturally it gives error. Is there a way I can change the name of class or give it some kind of alias so let's say "staticclass" in "one.dll" will remain as it is, and I can give alias to "staticclassTwo" which is in "two.dll"

Please note I do not have access to source codec of both "one.dll" and "two.dll"

Comment: you can use the fully qualified name of the class -- i.e. include the namespace

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(I'm assuming the two classes are also in the same namespace. If they're not, it's easy - just use simple `using` directives for aliases, or the fully qualified name in the code.)

You can indeed give an alias - an [*extern alias*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx). Effectively this adds "assembly" as another level of namespace differentiation.

Obviously you should avoid this situation when you can, but it's nice that C# provides a way of being very explicit when you absolutely have to.

Anson Horton has a [good walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx) for how you use them in practice.

Comment: Those two classes may or may not be in same namespace. I don't know about it. I just add a reference of that DLL in my project and then when I type "staticclass" and give a dot after it, it gives me list of methods and properties available. I mean I do not even declare its namespace on top. Just add DLL and start using its class.

Comment: Ali if you open the references folder in solution explorer you can double click on the assembly and will open that assembly in the object browser. This will let you see exactly which namespaces this assembly has and the classes in those namesapces

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my previous comment and that is I am actually declaring namespace above. Both namespaces are same in both DLLs so I used extern alias as Jon Skeet told and it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply using *Alias*.

In your code, just below to the *namespace* line; **use *alias* as given below**:

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{

    using ClassOne = Assembly.One.MyClass; /* your dll 1 class */
    using ClassTwo = Assembly.Two.MyClass; /* your dll 2 class */

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ClassOne one = new ClassOne();
            // Do your stuff with ClassOne object

            ClassTwo two = new ClassTwo();
            // Do your stuff with ClassTwo object

        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!